# Connecting a hardrive to an ipad for iMovie

Tags: ipad, imovie, video-editing

Want to use my ipad for light movie editing computer. The 32 gigs is not cutting it. Is their a way to connect a hardrive to the ipad to use in imovie? I have in the past used icloud to store the bulk of the videos to edit on the ipad. This worked but i had to pay a few dollars a month, download the video files i wanted to splice and i could not work off line.

Comment: In short, no. You cannot expand any iDevice by hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use an external hard drive in combination with iMovie on any iPad.

If you are looking to expand your storage space you can look into a [Seagate Wireless Plus hard drive](http://www.seagate.com/ca/en/external-hard-drives/portable-hard-drives/wireless/wireless-plus/), but you will have to store the video files locally in order to edit them with iMovie.